# Listing inputs on Python by using XML and array

Tags: python, xml, arrays, list, input

I want to sort some kind of functions by Python and XML, but I'm really confused about it.

I'll give you an example,

There are 3 input options that contains in a config.xml file.

```
<inputs>
    <input1 value='1- Sending Email' />
    <input2 value='2- Extracting a Tar File' />
    <input3 value='3- Rebooting Server' />
</inputs>
```

--

So, I have already pythoned each function in a folder named "funcs" and I have no problems with them.

All I want is;

1- Listing the inputs and ask for which one to choose.

2- And I need to do it by array. Because I only want to update the XML file in the future, so I'll never touch the main file that lets python to do every functions.

Any help will make me grateful, thank you.

Comment: You're trying to ask a complete question, but the details still are not clear.  What coding problem do you have now and what you you tried so far to accomplish 1 and 2, above

Comment: I am asking for a code that lists new inputs on main python file (when i running it) if I add an input to XML. I didn't used any codes yet, because I don't know what to use. Thats what I ask for.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a module to put all your functions inside, and then import them for use on your main program. So, in this module, you could also include the input messages (already associated with their respective functions), and get rid of the xml at all OR at least have this association defined in just one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves a bit of mindreading, but I think I know what you're looking for...  I built a file called `inputs.xml` that contains the xml you referenced above, then I read it and stored the inputs in a python dictionary called `inputs`

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

inputs = dict()
tree = ElementTree.parse( 'inputs.xml' )
for row in tree.getiterator('inputs'):
    for elem in row.getchildren():
        inputs[elem.tag] = elem.get('value')
```

The results...

```py
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01) 
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> 
>>> inputs = dict()
>>> tree = ElementTree.parse( 'inputs.xml' )
>>> for row in tree.getiterator('inputs'):
...     for elem in row.getchildren():
...         inputs[elem.tag] = elem.get('value')
... 
>>> print inputs
{'input2': '2- Extracting a Tar File', 'input3': '3- Rebooting Server', 'input1': '1- Sending Email'}
>>>
```

Now suppose you take input from a user and store it as a string in a python variable called `input`... if you want to access what choice the user selected, use `inputs["input"+input]`...

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I need a little bit more info.

When I want to send mail, so type 1 and hit enter. What will happen next? How will Python know what I type?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more an architectural problem than a Python problem.

If you have a Bunch of Functions you never want to touch, you should have each function associated with an imput message somewhere (most probably on the same source code of the function, and not in a xml).

You could, for example, put all the functions in a single file and import it as a module.

Then, when you run your program, you create a list of the functions you want to present to the user, sort them numerically someway, and display the input message for each function.

Example of module:

```
def reset():
    print "reset all"

def sendmail():
    print "send mail"

funcs = {
    "reset":     {"function": reset,    "message": "Choose to reset"},
    "sendmail":  {"function": sendmail, "message": "Choose to email someone"}
    }
```

By doing so, you xml should contain only the keys of the `funcs` dictionary. Then, for you to print the message, you should use `funcs['reset']['message']`, for example, and to use the function, you should use `funcs['reset']['function'](args)`.

It works, I have already used something very similar.

Comment: I will encrypt the sources, so I can not edit them in the future. Thats why I'm trying to merge it with a XML.

Comment: Fine. So at least consider having a strong association between each function and its input message, for example, using a dictionary.